# Why is return keyword required to exit loop?

Tags: ruby

In the `test2` method below, why is the `return` keyword needed in order for the method's return to not equal `nil`?

In `test`, `return` isn't required. The last line the program evaluates (`true` or `false`) becomes the return

```
def test
  x = gets.chomp

  if x == 'yes'
    true
  else
    false
  end
end

result = test
puts result # PRINTS 'TRUE' OR 'FALSE'
```

But in `test2`, if `return` isn't given on the lines indicated, the return value of the method will be `nil`.

```
def test2
  while true
    reply = gets.chomp.downcase

    if (reply == 'yes' || reply == 'no')
      if reply == 'yes'
        true      # RETURN NEEDED HERE
       else
        false     # RETURN NEEDED HERE
       end
      break

     else
      puts 'Please answer "yes" or "no".'
    end
  end
end

result2 = test2
puts result2        # PRINTS NIL
```

The examples are adapted from Chris Pine's How to Program, where it states the return key is necessary here to quit the loop. But why should this return a value, if the last line to be evaluated is still either `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't use `return`, the last statement in your method is the `while` loop itself, which evaluates to `nil`. The result of the if inside your loop is not "carried" over when you break out of the loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use `break` to provide a return value for `while`:

```
if reply == 'yes'
  break true
 else
  break false
end
```